# Cross-year DatePeriod width DateInterval P7D losing new year week

Tags: php, date

I'm trying to have an array of yearweeks using PHP DatePeriod like so :

```
$from = new DateTime('2014-09-16');
$to = new DateTime('2015-02-25');

$interval = new DateInterval('P7D'); // 7Days => 1 Week
$daterange = new DatePeriod($from, $interval, $to);

$yearweeks = array();
foreach($daterange as $date) {
    $yearweeks[$date->format('YW')] = 'W' . $date->format('W-Y');
}
```

The result is pretty strange ! 
The first week of the new year is missing. I have fist week of previous year instead like so :

```
Array
(
    ...
    [201451] => W51-2014
    [201452] => W52-2014
    [201401] => W01-2014 // WTF ? /!\ [201501] => W01-2015 expected ! /!\
    [201502] => W02-2015
    [201503] => W03-2015
    ...
)
```

Is there a trick to avoid this kind of error ?

Comment: what was the error?and what is your expected output ?

Comment: @deadman I updated the result array with a comment. Basically 201401 instead of 201501

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use ISO year, which is format 'o':

```
$yearweeks[$date->format('oW')] = 'W' . $date->format('W-o');
```

From the [PHP `date` docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php):

> o
>
> ISO-8601 year number. This has the same value as Y, except that if
>   the ISO week number (W) belongs to the previous or next year, that
>   year is used instead. (added in PHP 5.1.0)
>
> Examples: 1999 or 2003

Comment: It works ! Than you sir. Could you briefly explain what's the difference between 'Y' and 'o' ?

Comment: @Pye: I added links to the docs, which provide some explanation.  The way I think of it is that `Y` is like the mathematical `floor` function, and `o` is like `round`.  During the last week of the year, you've got kind of a fractional week: some of it is in previous year, some of it is in next.  You need to figure out which "side" of that "fraction" to go to.  'Y' just *floors* it, which is wrong for some part of the week.  'o' *rounds* it the direction you need it: if 12/31 or fewer, then round down, if 1/1 or higher, round up.